# One perl script many "terminals" (tmux panes)

Tags: perl, tmux

How to make perl script start tmux child process with a few (2) tmux panes seen by the script as (write only) file descriptors?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub get_handles {
   # some tmux magic    

   return @handles; # return array of two file descriptors, preferably IO::Handle
}
```

I need it for script using AnyEvent module (or threads).

Comment: According to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) it seems that `tmux split-window [shell-command]` can be used to create a pipe to a process running in a new pane. Also it says: *"An empty shell-command ('') will create a pane with no command running in it.  Output can be sent to such a pane with the display-message command."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/567 gives exaple how to get list of pseudo terminal devices (file paths).

```
tmux list-panes -F'#{pane_tty} #{pane_id}'
```